# Get directions by nickname in Siri

Tags: contacts, siri

Asking Siri to get Maps directions to someone’s address, is it possible somehow to refer to the relevant contact by its **nickname** (as its defined in the Contacts app) instead of by long first and last name combination?

That is,

> Hi Siri, show me directions to Rob

Instead of

> Hi Siri, show me directions to Robert Pattinson

I am asking specifically to iOS but an answer for MacOS is also appreciated

Comment: I can ring my partner just by first name "Call [name]…mobile" (I've never tried directions, we live in the same house;)) but she's the only one with that first name in my contacts.

Comment: Your first example works for me. I’m using the official nickname field with a unique nickname (i.e. there is nobody named “Rob” in my contacts).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, if you asking for this kind of request to Siri directly Siri gives you full name , even you have their nickname.

Shortcuts on iOS and iPadOS able to do that. Just create a new shortcut: add Map app -> add address... Name this short cuts as "directions to someone’s address".

After saving, ask Siri "directions to someone’s address",that's it.

Hope this helps, stay safe.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I've missed something in your answer. What do you mean by "Siri gives you full name"? I don't care what it gives me, but how is it processing what I gave. I need Siri to recognize nicknames, isn't it possible?